# Blazor WASM shows error 403 after publishing on iis with HTTPS protocol

Tags: iis, blazor, blazor-webassembly

My Blazor WASM .net5 project is not working after publishing on IIS 10. It shows a lot of errors in the console, almost all dlls throw 403 error, and some other errors that say **Unknown error occurred while trying to verify integrity**
I don't know if this related to blazor or related to iis. The only thing I found that is setting

```
<BlazorEnableCompression>false</BlazorEnableCompression>
```

into blazor project, bud didn't work. Now I don't know where can I start to find the solution. So any ideas with this ?

thank you

**Update**:

I am using publish window with Framework-Dependent as deployment mode, browser-wasm as target runtime

Comment: Have you run through the steps outlined for deploying WASM to IIS in Microsoft's documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: 403 error means there is a permission issue, you can use FRT to troubleshoot this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: @CoryPodojil yes but the same error

Comment: @DingPeng I will try this, but what happened now that it worked after we stopped firewall. But I think this is not ideal solution

Comment: Maybe use Kestrel instead of IIS to see if you still have the issues?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a web.config file in the iis website folder

[image]

that looks like this: Pay attention to the rewrite rules.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".blat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dll" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="CanonicalHost_HTPPS_Rule1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^alpha-clean\.gr$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://alpha-clean.gr/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="LowerCaseRule1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Serve subdir">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SPA fallback routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you want the file to be published along the project make sure the following is added to the project file:
`<PublishIISAssets>true</PublishIISAssets>`